# AWS ECS - Multiple containers on a single instance performance issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, multiprocessing, amazon-ecs

I'm using a **16 CPU instance** on AWS Elastic Container Service (ECS). And I want to run **8 containers** here, which **all reserve 2 CPUs**.

The performance I get with this setup is significantly slower (around doubly) than when I run **8 containers on 8 instances of 2 CPUs each**.

Currently, it seems like the CPU assignment isn't "hard", in that a container can be given more than 2 CPUs by the scheduler at any time.

Is there a way to "hard assign" CPUs to containers? My end goal is to make CPUs as specialized as possible for just a single task, so that the performance is better, i.e. closer to the performance I get when I run the containers on separate instances. If there are other steps I should be taking, I would appreciate pointers on them as well.

Note that the tasks that containers run are fully independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a couple points:

1. The "CPU" parameter of the ECS configuration will "reserve" the CPU for a given container. The CPU will always be able to use that much CPU with minimal delay. HOWEVER - that's not the maximum CPU (and there is no way to set a maximum cpu in ECS); containers are allowed to use unallocated CPU as desired. So if you had 1 container running with 2048 reserved CPU units, it will still be allowed to use all 16 CPUs until something else needs them.
2. The performance degradation you're seeing is likely a result of CPU thrashing where the containers need more CPU than you're giving them so they grab it from the other containers who aren't using it. Then when the other containers need it they need to grab from the container that's using it more, causing that to lose performance. You may need to right-size your containers.

After those two points, I have to ask: Running 8 smaller servers with 8 containers will fix this issue as you note (no more resource sharing between the 8 containers) and will be *much* cheaper. Why one big server instead of 8 smaller?

Comment: Hello Patrick, thanks for your reply! I totally agree on both of your points. I want to use as few instances as possible, because the scale of my actual problem is larger than just 8 containers ( think >200 containers that need to be run). And the compute environment is shared with more people, so I can't just spin up 200 instances; EC2 has instance limits). Also for my case it'd be actually the same cost to go from r4.large to r4.4xlarge instances if the performance didn't get hurt. ( x8 cost for x8 resources )

Comment: Also could you expand on "You may need to right-size your containers."? Currently they reserve 2048 CPU, but as you said it's problematic. I'd prefer to hard-assign CPUs to processes, so that they don't grab each others' resources.

Comment: I'd reach out to your account rep - those EC2 instances can be raised (we're running far more than that right now in a single cluster that does document processing). 200 containers on 200 instances is no problem. That having been said, if 8:1 is really the desired setup, EKS (Kubernetes) has a method of actually limiting your CPU per container - but that's a very substantial change architecturally.

Comment: What I meant by right-sizing your containers is that if they're reaching you to grab CPUs from other containers then 2 CPUs probably isn't enough. You may need 3 or 4 CPUs per container and to lower the number of containers per instance to get the performance you're looking for. 2 CPUs works fine on the other boxes because they don't starve each other, but the fact that they're trying to starve each other means it would probably run faster with 3-4 cpus on a larger box. You may not want that due to cost, and I definitely understand that.

Comment: I see, then there is no trivial way to solve it in ECS. EKS is in preview currently I believe? Thanks @Patrick, accepted as answer!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately not. Yeah, EKS is in previous, so not a great solution right now. Thanks for the accept :)